# R fitting competing models to nested data within the dplyr/tidyr/broom framework

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to fit model subsets to a nested data frame. While I have seen many examples of fitting the same model to different groups of data, I have yet to come across an example that fits different models to a dataset that is organized as a nested dataframe.

As an example, I have taken code from the R For Data Science "Many Models" section. Here, the goal was to fit the same model to different countries (groups). What I am hoping to do is to expand this and fit multiple different competing models to the different countries (groups). Ideally, each competing model would then be stored as a new column in the nested dataframe.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
# Example code 
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(modelr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(gapminder)

# Create nested data
by_country <- gapminder %>% 
  group_by(country, continent) %>% 
  nest()

# Model 1
country_model <- function(df) {
  lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = df)
}

# Map model 1 to the data
by_country <- by_country %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, country_model))

# Model 2
country_model2 <- function(df) {
  lm(lifeExp ~ year + gdpPercap, data = df)
}

# Map Model 2 to the data
by_country <- by_country %>% 
  mutate(model2 = map(data, country_model2))
```

UPDATED
To clarify my question, I know I could manually do this with a call to mutate for each of the models. I think what I am after is something more flexible, almost something similar to the code below. However, instead of functions "runif", "rnorm" and "rpois", these functions would be calls to model functions. For example "country_model" and "country_model2". Hopefully that helps a bit.

```
# Example code
 sim <- dplyr::frame_data(
  ~f,      ~params,
  "runif", list(min = -1, max = -1),
  "rnorm", list(sd = 5),
  "rpois", list(lambda = 10)
 )
sim %>% dplyr::mutate(
  samples = invoke_map(f, params, n = 10)
)
```

Comment: I may be missing what your goal is.  Can't you put the two models within the same `mutate`?  I.e., `mutate(model = map(data, country_model), model2 = map(data, country_model2))`

Comment: Hi AO, yes this would definitely work. I think what I am looking for would be a more flexible process. So instead of typing out each of the models in that fashion, could you somehow pass them (maybe in a list?) and then do something more like pmap, which would map each of the different models to the data?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses the invoke_map function mentioned in your update.

It involves creating three functions. These functions:
 1.  Create a data frame in which your models are specified
 2.  Use the invoke_map function to apply these models to your data
 3.  Reshape the results, so that they can be added as columns in your original by_country data frame

```r
# Example code 
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(modelr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(gapminder)

# Create nested data
by_country <- gapminder %>% 
  group_by(country, continent) %>% 
  nest()

# Function that creates dataframe suitable for invoke_map function
create_model_df  <- 
  function(x){  
    dplyr::frame_data(
      ~model_name,    ~f,     ~params,
      "country_model", "lm", list(formula =as.formula("lifeExp ~ year + gdpPercap"), data = x ),
      "country_model2","lm", list(formula =as.formula("lifeExp ~ year"),data = x )
    )     
  }

# Function that applies invoke_map function 
apply_models  <- 
  function(x){        
    x %>% 
      mutate( model_fit = invoke_map(f, params)) 
  }

# Function that the results from invoke map
reshape_results  <- 
  function(x){   
    x %>% 
      select(model_name,model_fit) %>% spread(model_name,model_fit)
  }

# Apply these functions 
by_country %>% 
  mutate(model_df = data %>% 
           map(create_model_df) %>% 
           map(apply_models) %>% 
           map(reshape_results)) %>% 
  unnest(model_df) 
#> # A tibble: 142 x 5
#>        country continent              data country_model country_model2
#>         <fctr>    <fctr>            <list>        <list>         <list>
#>  1 Afghanistan      Asia <tibble [12 x 4]>      <S3: lm>       <S3: lm>
#>  2     Albania    Europe <tibble [12 x 4]>      <S3: lm>       <S3: lm>
#>  3     Algeria    Africa <tibble [12 x 4]>      <S3: lm>       <S3: lm>
#>  4      Angola    Africa <tibble [12 x 4]>      <S3: lm>       <S3: lm>
#>  5   Argentina  Americas <tibble [12 x 4]>      <S3: lm>       <S3: lm>
#>  6   Australia   Oceania <tibble [12 x 4]>      <S3: lm>       <S3: lm>
#>  7     Austria    Europe <tibble [12 x 4]>      <S3: lm>       <S3: lm>
#>  8     Bahrain      Asia <tibble [12 x 4]>      <S3: lm>       <S3: lm>
#>  9  Bangladesh      Asia <tibble [12 x 4]>      <S3: lm>       <S3: lm>
#> 10     Belgium    Europe <tibble [12 x 4]>      <S3: lm>       <S3: lm>
#> # ... with 132 more rows
```